# How to fix built-in function in write context

Tags: php

The following `=&` creates error in php7.2 or above. I am not sure how to fix this problem. Any inputs will be appreciated.

```
public function title()
{
    // If we have some segments passed
    // this line creates an error
    if ($title_segments =& func_get_args())
    {
        $this->_title = implode($this->_title_separator, $title_segments);
    }

    return $this;
}

...

public function get_by()
{
    // this line creates an error
    $where =& func_get_args();
    $this->_set_where($where);

    return $this->db->get($this->_table)
        ->row();
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? it must be NOTICE and not error which you can make silent using `@` in front of the line.

Comment: @Viney As in the title *Fatal error: Cannot use result of built-in function in write context* https://3v4l.org/ROP02

Comment: I would suggest using the PHP 5.6+ [Variadic Functions  `...`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) instead of `func_get_args()`, but it can not be used to pass the arguments by reference. Though I am unsure if passing-by reference is necessary in this context. Effectively passing-by reference is not being used that I can see.

Comment: @fyrye I see! didn't know in 7.2 they changed it to E_ERROR.

Comment: @Vinay were you able to figure this out? were you also using:

 * A base model to provide the basic CRUD
 * actions for all models that inherit from it.
 *
 * package CodeIgniter
 * subpackage MY_Model
 * link http://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model
 * author Jamie Rumbelow <http://jamierumbelow.net>

Answer (score 1):

What you're writing doesn't make sense at all. `func_get_args()` returns an array of arguments; if you could get a reference to that array, you would be able to modify the actual argument list of the function (consider doing `array_pop()` on it).

Let me show you an example, without the fluff:

```
function add_nums ($first, $second) {
  return $first + $second;
}
```

Simple enough. `add_nums(10, 25)` returns 35.

Now, what if you call `func_get_args()` in there? You'd get `[10, 25]`. But that array *doesn't exist* — it's nowhere in your code. The engine is creating it from the argument list, but it doesn't really come from your code.

What would a reference to that array mean? It could be a reference to the copy that `func_get_args()` creates for you, or to the actual argument list. In the former case, it would be no better than the actual array; it would make no sense to think of it as a reference, since a further call to `func_get_args()` would create a new copy straight from the original. And in the latter case, you'd need to create a special reference that points to the engine internals so that you can modify a function's argument list after the function has been called — which is quite a weird concept to begin with. For instance, if you could get a reference to the argument list in that example and called `array_pop()` on it, the engine would have to update its internal structures to reflect that the call is now `add_nums(10)`, not `add_nums(10, 25)`.

And this is why you can't get a reference to the argument list. `$foo =& func_get_args()` is nonsensical — there is no workaround.

Comment: Well written! Thank you for your efforts. I would like to add there is a technical workaround by passing on object, as they are assigned by reference and using `func_get_args()` with the object property, https://3v4l.org/iqdfM but it is not being used in this manner in the question.

Comment: @fyrye Thanks! And that will give you a reference to the object itself, but certainly not to the argument list — if you passed other values along with the object, modifying the object would obviously not affect those values (assuming that the object doesn't contain references to them). The concept of a reference to the argument list itself is what is problematic.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I posted an answer explaining the issues related as well. :) None-the-less still upvoted you for the effort you put in. Keep up the good answers!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific use-case that you can provide, since the intended usage of referencing the values passed to the function from `func_get_args()` is not supported in any version of PHP, I suggest simply removing the by-reference assignment operator `&`.

Ultimately it will not work as I believe is intended, and will emit a warning in `PHP < 7.2`, or a Fatal Error in `PHP 7.2+`.

> `PHP 4.4.0 - 4.4.9, 7.0.0 - 7.1.25`
>
> *Notice: Only variables should be assigned by reference*
>
> `PHP 5.0.5 - 5.6.38`
>
> *Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference*

Furthermore, objects will be assigned by-reference as of `PHP 5.0+` [[sic]](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) and it is not necessary to pass them by-reference.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/oEH3G

```
function title()
{
    $title_segments =& func_get_args();

    //change argument 1 ($a) to C
    $title_segments[0] = 'C'; 

    var_dump($title_segments);
}

$a = 'A';
title($a);

//passing by reference in PHP < 7.2 does not result in intended results of $a = 'C'
var_dump($a);
```

**Result:**

```
//var_dump($title_segments)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "C"
}

//var_dump($a)
string(1) "A"
```

---

For slightly improved performance and readability. I suggest using the PHP 5.6+ [Variadic Functions ...](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) instead of `func_get_args()`, which will produce the same results.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/iQNP0

```
function title(...$title_segments)
{
    $title_segments[0] = 'C'; 

    var_dump($title_segments);
}
```